# How to execute code to display a PivotItem?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `Pivot` named `MyPivot`, and a `PivotItem` named `MyPivotItem`.
I would like to run the code every time I see the `MyPivotItem`. Is that right?

```
if (MyPivot.SelectedItem == MyPivotItem)
{
    //...
}
```

The code, however, did not work.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but you have to hook `SelectionChanged` event which fires when you swipe pivot pages to execute it.

XAML

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="MyPivot" 
             Title="TITLE" 
             SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
    <phone:PivotItem x:Name="MyPivotItem" 
                     Header="one" />
    <phone:PivotItem x:Name="AnotherPivotItem" 
                     Header="two" />
</phone:Pivot>
```

C#

```
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyPivot.SelectedItem == MyPivotItem)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not compare the SelectedIndex?

```
if (MyPivot.SelectedIndex == someIndex)
{

}
```

where someIndex is index of your MyPivotItem.

Comment: I can put any number, but the code is never executed

Comment: That's weird. If you set someIndex to 1, and swipe your pivot item, what's the value of MyPivot.SelectedIndex?